# how to get hex string from a HexBytes object?

Tags: python, web3py

```
>>> from hexbytes import HexBytes
>>> ...
>>> hb
HexBytes('0x53b983fe73e16f6ed8178f6c0e0b91f23dc9dad4cb30d0831f178')
```

I have a HexBytes object `hb`.

I want to get `0x53b983fe73e16f6ed8178f6c0e0b91f23dc9dad4cb30d0831f178` string, what should I do?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can just type `hb.hex()` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

never worked with this module but this should do the job:

```
hexdecimal = "".join(["{:02X}".format(b) for b in hb])
```